# Set default time in angular modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time, model, default

How can i set a default time value in a angular model?

HTML

```
<input id="starttime_mon" name="starttime_mon" ng-model="starttime[1]" ng-disabled="!search_dow_number[1]" type="time" class="form-control" />
<input id="endtime_mon" name="endtime_mon" ng-model="endtime[1]" ng-disabled="!search_dow_number[1]" type="time" class="form-control"  />
```

JS

```
$scope.starttime = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
$scope.starttime = '00:00;
$scope.starttime[1] = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

on the last attempt i get:Error: Cannot set property '1' of undefined
The other things i tried didn't give any result.

Comment: What are you trying to do actually? Just remove that bracket. In case you need filter you can filter it in the controller by getting the index.

Comment: I see you asked a lot of question without marking one as right. Please mark the right answer in your questions. I would help other users and its how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 1):

So `new Date`, means that `$scope.starttime` is not an object, so it does not have the `1` property you're trying to get from it using `$scope.starttime[1]`

Having a bit of a hard time understanding what you mean, but I don't think you need the [1]:

JS

`$scope.starttime = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);`

HTML

`<input id="starttime_mon" name="starttime_mon" ng-model="starttime" ...`

Comment: Thx but i do need the [1]. I'm using this in a filter for ng-repeat.

Comment: Can you post more code? I have a feeling you can do it a bit better in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:

```
  <input type="time" ng-model="timeModel"/> 
  $scope.timeModel = new Date(2010, 11, 28, 14, 57);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DIvGpXrPkmqRMnNpDWlH?p=preview . Hope it helps

Comment: this put me in the right direction. What i have to do is:$scope.timeModel = new Date(2010, 11, 28, 14, 57);
$scope.timeModel[1] = new Date(2010, 11, 28, 14, 57);$scope.timeModel[2] = new Date(2010, 11, 28, 14, 57);.....